# How to position a seekbar like youtube which overlaps with bottom area?

Tags: android

[image]
We are implementing an ui where there are two fragments as per the attached pic.
On the top fragment we are playing a video. We need to implement the seekbar as shown in the picture where the scrubbar overlaps with the bottom fragment. 
Have tried to put the seekbar in fragment1, But it doesn't come in the boundary section and doesn't overlaps with bottom fragment. If i try to put some -ve bottom margin scrubbar truncates from bottom.
What could be the design option for this case.

Comment: Have you tried doing it with `constraintLayout` yet

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'll check with constraint layout. By any chance if anyone has a sample xml for this, will be help for quick reference .